# Translation of travelling wave is again a travelling wave, thus $0$ is an eigenvalue: Why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

If we have a travelling wave solution $y(\xi)$ and translate it to $y(\xi-\xi_0)$, this is again a travelling wave.

It is claimed the following:

> If we linearize along a travelling wave, the associated Jacobian therefore has eigenvalue $0$. This is because of the fact that a translation of a travelling wave is again a travelling wave.

Why is this the case? Do not see why the Jacobian has to have eigenvalue $0$.

Could you please explain that to me?